# Java 8 convert Map<Integer, List<String>> to Map<String, List<Integer>> with

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

I have a Map is a map to a list of values but I need to inverse it so that

```
Map<Integer, List<String>>
```

becomes

```
Map<String, List<Integer>>
```

For example I have

```
1 -> { A, B, C }
2 -> { B }
3 -> { A, C }
```

and I want to see

```
A -> { 1, 3 }
B -> { 1, 2 }
C -> { 1, 3 }
```

Is there any easier way in Java 8 to do this than having to iterate through the map entries and create a set entry if it does not exist, and add to the list etc? I keep thinking it is really obvious but I cannot work it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Probably a dup, sure, but it provides a nice Java 8 update to the listed question. Perhaps our esteemed Mr. Wasserman would care to provide his answer on the linked dup?

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom I already have an answer on that question ;) I suppose I could edit it to add another

Comment: Thanks for the pointers to the duplicate - it was mainly that I was determined to get it working with Java 8 and the answer below fitted the requirement.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I think that would make a good edit. Your existing answer was excellent at the time and still works, but updating for Java 8 would be worth the effort IMO. (Especially since it isn't my effort ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Untested, but you could do something like this:

```
mapIntToStrings.entrySet().stream()
   .flatMap(entryIntToStrings -> entryIntToStrings.getValue().stream()
       .map(str -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entryIntToStrings.getKey(), str)))
   .collect(groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, mapping(Map.Entry::getKey, toList())))
```

Comment: What is `entryIntToStrings`?

Comment: @Andreas whoops, fixed, it was the argument to the lambda.

Comment: This would be a nice answer on the linked dup question. Just sayin'. :-)

Comment: Thanks for that. I had missed AbstractMap.SimpleEntry. So near and yet so far... :)