# How to filter multivalued map with list

Tags: java, java-stream

I have request parameters coming in and trying to remove the parameters that are empty.

```
http://example.com/get/users?dept=admin&dept=&area=999
```

Here I want to remove empty dept from my request parameters before passing it on to the database query.

```
private Map<String, List<String>> getUsers(MultiValueMap<String, String> args) {
        return args.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(i -> i.getValue().stream()
                        .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank). // return only non empty values
                        .anyMatch(s -> !s.isEmpty()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
```

I'm expecting the output to be like

```
"dept" -> ["admin"]
"area" -> ["999"]

If http://example.com/get/users?dept=&dept=&area=999 all the dept values are empty then totally remove dept from the map

"area" -> ["999"]
```

Edit: Current behaviour

1. If http://example.com/get/users?dept=&dept=&area=999 then

```
"area" -> ["999"]
```

2. If http://example.com/get/users?dept=admin&dept=&area=999 then

```
"area" -> ["999"]
"dept" -> ["", "admin"]
```

Instead I want just

```
"area" -> ["999"]
"dept" -> ["admin"]
```

Comment: you can remove the values which are empty using `values.removeIf`

Comment: Can you tell us what is the content of `MultiValueMap<String, String> args`?

Comment: And what is not working with your current solution? It seems working

Comment: You have mentioned your expected output, but you haven't posted the actual output.

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`flatMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-). See this [demo on IDEone](https://ideone.com/HAJiPZ):

```java
Map<String, List<String>> requestParams = Map.of("dept", List.of("a", "  "), "area", List.of("x"));
var result = requestParams.entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().stream()
        .flatMap(Stream::of) // flatten the list to a stream to process further
        // .filter( StringUtils::isNotBlank )
        .filter(s -> s != null && !s.isBlank()) // return only non empty values
        .collect(Collectors.toList()) // collect as List (to return as entry)
    ))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
System.out.println(result);
```

It has two levels:

1. outer: **map to a new entry** and collect
2. inner: filter the values (List) for all non-blank Strings

If you also want to exclude parameters that have a key but no value (i.e. `null` or empty List), then you would add a filter for that before the last `.collect` to Map:

`.filter(entry -> entry.getValue() != null && !entry.getValue().isEmpty())`

See also:

- [Java 8 convert Map<Integer, List<String>> to Map<String, List<Integer>> with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34999568/java-8-convert-mapinteger-liststring-to-mapstring-listinteger-with)

Comment: And if `MultiValueMap` allows (mutable) you could also `removeIf` the empty values conditionally, like _Naman_ suggested That would __simplify__: (1) reduce a lot of streaming and (2) does not require new instance creation for map, entries, list of strings.